# Machine learning - Text extraction / pattern identification

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining, information-extraction

I am new to machine learning, There will be set of paragraph and i need to extract postcode from each paragraph.  (The postcode may not have the same pattern as they are obtained from different countries)  The model should learn from the training data and should predict for the test data.  Is there any R package to implement this, if yes, an small example can help.

```
Updated with example:
```

For example consider the below training set with Mdescription and Mcode

S.No. Mdescription Mcode

1 "Pansaonic P4725 has 5mp camera" "P4725"

2 "Metallic Plate 06279 is 62*79 cm area" "06279"

Here i need a machine learning model to learn to predict Mcode from Mdescription for new test data

For implementing this are there any machine learning algorithm . I use R as programming language. Is there any R package available for training the model and using it to make new predictions?

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more? You already have Mcode in Mdescription, whats the need of prediction?

Comment: Thanks for your time.Yes, I already have Mcode in Mdescription. I need to extract the Mcode from the Mdescription. Now what I have is a large training set with 2 columns one is the Mdescription and other is the Mcode(dependent variable).The mode should learn from the training set and should be able to extract the Mcode(information extraction/entity recognition) for the new test data.For implementing this are there any machine learning algorithms so that it can be used to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for your time.Yes I already have **Mcode** in **Mdescription**. I need to extract(or filter) the **Mcode** from the **Mdescription**. Now what I have is a large training set with 2 columns one is the Mdescription and other is the Mcode(dependent variable).The model should learn from the training set and should be able to extract the Mcode(information extraction/entity recognition) for the new test data.For implementing this are there any machine learning algorithms so that it can be used to solve the problem

Comment: This is not really a prediction problem, it is a data extraction logic problem. You need to form some rules for extracting the model number from your input variables. e.g. you pick up the first word, where a number appears in string.